# How can I get protractor to wait for a login before proceeding?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I have a non-angular entry page to my app and I'm trying to first login:

```
describe('Authentication', function() {
  it('should authenticate a user', function() {
    browser.driver.get('https://example.com')

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys("user");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys("mypass");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.tagName('input')).click()
    var url = browser.getLocationAbsUrl()
    browser.driver.sleep(1)
    browser.waitForAngular()

    return
  })
})
```

However, this gives an error:

```
 Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or bec
ause your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: non-angular, you need to set `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` before executing your commands on that page.  Also, just FYI, `sleep` is in milliseconds, not seconds.  You are waiting 0.001 seconds with that currently

Comment: I added `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` and got the same error

Comment: Wow sorry, I meant `true`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote some helpers in the past to get this work in my e2e-tests:

```
waitForUrlToChangeTo: function (urlToMatch) {
    var currentUrl;
    return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function storeCurrentUrl(url) {
            currentUrl = url;
        })
       .then(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
            browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
            return browser.wait(function waitForUrlToChangeTo() {
                return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function compareCurrentUrl(url) {
                    browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
                    return url.indexOf(urlToMatch) !== -1;
                });
            });
        }
    );
},
login : function (username, password, url) {
    browser.get('#/login');
    element(by.model('username')).sendKeys(username);
    element(by.model('password')).sendKeys(password);
    element(by.buttonText('LOGIN')).click();
    return this.waitForUrlToChangeTo(url);
}
```

And then in tests:

```
describe('when I login with valid credentials', function() {
    it('should redirect to dashboard', function() {
        helper.login('user', 'pass', '#/dashboard').then(function() {
            expect(browser.getTitle()).toMatch('Dashboard');
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I get the same error ` Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "window.angular is undefined.  This could be either because this is a non-angular page or bec
ause your test involves client-side navigation, which can interfere with Protractor's bootstrapping.  See http://git.io/v4gXM for details"`

Answer (score 1):

I would say wait for logged in page until it displays properly and than do action. For e.g,

- Target some element in logged-in page and wait for it.
- Wait for url change, etc.

> login -> browser.sleep(500)/wait for logged in page's element/URL change ->
>   other action

```
 browser.driver.wait(function(){
     expectedElement.isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible){
            return isVisible === true;
          },50000, 'Element not present ');
 },50000);
```

> if that element is not present within specified time, timeout error
>   would display & you would know unitl that time it's not logged in.